# Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19678 Exception code: 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2019

I had a VC++ project (console application) built on VS2013. It was working successfully for a long time. Recently we have converted that project to VS2019 (PlatformToolset 142). Now the latest exe is crashing after some operation with below error.

> Faulting application name: abc.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x5eb3101a Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19678,
>   time stamp: 0x5e82c88a Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x0000000000030837 Faulting process id: 0x137c Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d624424de8d7e1 Faulting application path:  Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id:
>   8bad3b06-9035-11ea-80de-d6b5b2fa72df Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

One big observation is VS2019 exe is half size of VS2013 exe. How to debug further to find out the root cause of the application crash?

After run-in remote debug found that it is throwing an unhandled exception at

```
HeapAlloc( m_hHeap, HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, _Count * sizeof( value_type ));
```

This was working perfectly with VC2013. This HeapAlloc issue I am getting whenever we are calling std::vector related operation. Is anything got change related to this in VS2019/VC++2019 ?

Comment: *It was working successfully for a long time.* -- Maybe the new compiler revealed a bug that always existed.  However, you really didn't ask a question.

Comment: You will likely going to have to use your debugger to track this down. Don't assume its the compiler's fault. With that said make sure that 100% of your application was built with VS 2015 or greater.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Updated the question

Comment: @drescherjm It is built with VS2019, with that .exe only getting the above crash

Comment: My advice is spend 20 minutes and follow this tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019) once you learn how to use your debugger you should be able to get it to tell you what line of your code was executing when the program had the access violation. Have it break on this exception and switch the callstack to your code.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for your inputs. Is this exe size difference between VS2013 and VS2019 expected?

Comment: My Visual Studio 2019 executables  are usually 20%+ larger then VS2013 however I package the runtime inside my installer.